# How to append column data if no match has found?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table1 and table2 as following

Table1

```
first_name | last_name | t1_id
```

Table2

```
T2_id | color | length
```

Table1 may have an id value which doesn't exist in Table2 id, however it may exist sometimes. I want to write a query that gives the following result:
First_name | last_name | t1_id | color | length
Where in case if the id value doesn't exist in table2 the result should be like:

```
First_name | last_name | t1_id | color | length
-----------------------------------------------
Johan      | Mike      | 33    |   -   |   -
```

My try:

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       t1_id,
       color,
       length
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE t1_id = t2_id
```

But this show the result when the value of `t1_id` only exists in `t2_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT` join to get all rows from first table even if their associations are not present in second table

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       t1_id,
       color,
       length
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON t1_id = t2_id
```

You could use `COALESCE(column,'-')` to show `-` if column is null

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       t1_id,
       COALESCE(color,'-'),
       COALESCE(length,'-')
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON t1_id = t2_id
```

Comment: how to add `-` instead of getting null values when there is no match in the id as I shown in the result ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Left Join

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       t1_id,
       color,
       length
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON t1_id = t2_id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql **[left join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html)** join in this case if right table data not found then null

```
SELECT t1.first_name,
       t1.last_name,
       t1.t1_id,
       t2.color,
       t2.length
FROM table1  t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.t1_id = t2.t2_id;
```

in this sql i use alias but if you do not want it then

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       t1_id,
       color,
       length
    FROM table1  
    LEFT JOIN table2  
    ON t1_id = t2_id;
```

for more information

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of [LEFT JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2
ON t1_id = t2_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       t1_id,
       color,
       length
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE t1_id = t2_id(+)
```

Regards,
Damodar